# How to expand a token defined with \let

Tags: tex-core

At the end of the following code, the token list will contains the token `\val` and not the character `a` as confirmed by the `\showthe`. Using a `\def` instead of a `\let` gives the result I want but is not an option in my real case.

```
\newtoks\tok
\let\val=a
\tok=\expandafter{\val}
\showthe\tok
```

In the full macro, I'm inserting multiple characters one by one in the token list so instead of getting something like `abc` I get `\val\val\val` and so when I use the token list the result is like `ccc`, using the last value of `\val`.

I cannot change the `\let` as the macro use `\afterassignement` to read the input character by character like this:

```
\def\reader{\afterassignement\process\let\val=}
```

Is there a way to get the character put in the token list instead of the token ? I understand that the `\token` created by `\let` is in some way not an expandable token and that the substitution should be triggered differently but I've found no way to do it.

Comment: If you `\def\val{a}` rather than `\let\val=a`, then you will end up with `a`.  But maybe it would help if you explained the bigger problem you are trying to accomplish.  My `tokcycle` package is made to cyle through tokens one by one and has the ability to peek ahead at what is next in the input.

Comment: Not sure how `tokcycle` is implemented or how well-behaved is it (for one I think it discards char code of braces), but there's also expl3's `peek_analysis_map_inline` which is supposed to do what you want (unfortunately has a few bugs at the moment as well.)

Answer (score 1):

the token is not expandable, you can look at the main loop in the `bm` package to see one way of distinguishing such tokens, basically you need to execute `\meaning\val` and see if that starts with `the letter`  and if so the letter is the next token.

Answer (score 1):

For example the macro `\addtotoks` does what you want:

```
\def\addtotoks#1 #2 #3\end#4{\expandafter{\the#4#3}}

\newtoks\tok
\let\val=a
\tok=\expandafter\addtotoks\meaning\val\end\tok
\let\val=b
\tok=\expandafter\addtotoks\meaning\val\end\tok

\showthe\tok  % result > ab
```

But warning: the `\meaning` primitive has various output formats for various tokens. The `\addtotoks` macro expects that there is an output of `\meaning` of a letter or a digit. And the result has category 12 regardles the actual category code 11 or 12 when `\let` was done.